# Можно ли сделать, что повторяющиеся объекты не дублировались в памяти?

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть два списка:

```
List<TestObject> testObject1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<TestObject> testObject2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Внутренние объекты могут повторятся.

Можно ли сделать, что бы эти повторяющиеся объекты не дублировались в памяти?

То есть занимали одну область памяти вместо двух?

Comment: это зависит как вы туда их добавляете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<TestObject> testObject1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<TestObject> testObject2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Если сделать

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
testObject1.add(testObject);
testObject2.add(testObject);
```

тогда один объект будет в 2 списках

Comment: а если объекты допустим читаются из базы(создаются каждый раз новые), и я заранее не знаю будут ли одинаковые. В этом случае возможно избежать повторения в памяти?

Comment: если из базы и уверены что они одинаковы при каждом запросе (обычно не так) тогда можете найти элемент из первого списка по ID и передать его 2му списку

Comment: Каждый раз при добавлении нового объекта во второй список, проверять существует ли объект в первом, будет ли это хорошим решением? Может лучше дублировать объекты?

Comment: @iamtihonov лучше дублировать объекты, или создать 2й список из первого. Каждый раз проверять это конечно плохо. Но автор этого хочет